# Avoid the Man-In the-Middle-Attack

Tags: arp

Assume I,m in a LAN, that uses a Router. If someone redirects my all data packets to his computer then there is no privacy. This is happening in real. when I run "arp -a" command, I can see his IP address and I couldn't remove it using command "arp -d ". Does anyone know a way to avoid this arp access? or any other suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is "ARP protocol Vulnerability" which is in the OSI model. As far as I know , this is under research & currently UNRESOLVED. iN lINUX U CAN AVOID THIS BY USING IPTABLES.

Answer (score 2):

Once a packet leaves your computer, there is really nothing you can do to choose where it goes or who captures it.  It's best to always assume that anyone can capture and observe all of your traffic on the network.  If that is not acceptable, you should use a protocol (e.g., SSL) that encrypts the communication.

Comment: Your're telling me that there is nothing to do with that?. However I don't know about SSL and how to use it as well. Can you tell me about that or refer me to an easy tutorial?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are doing or what your are looking for.  You can google for things like SSL, HTTPS, network protocols, etc. There is a lot of information out there.